ONE BOOK 3Dで特定のボタンの削除
ONE BOOK 3Dで特定のボタンを削除することはできますか。
jQueryPluginをダウンロードして、Html、CSSでカスタマイズしています。
jsは触っていません。
jsの知識が疎いこともあり、ダウンロードボタンと拡大ボタンを非表示かつクリックもできないようにしたいのですが
どのファイルの修正が必要で、どこをどのように記述すれば実現できるか分かりません。
▼削除したい両端のボタン

